# Crash in VMWare Clarity while accessing a page in pagination grid with below Stack

Tags: vmware-clarity

We are observing a crash in VMWare Clarity while programmatically accessing a page in pagination grid and it crashes with below Stack.

```
ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'get' of undefined
 at ClrDatagridRow.get [as _view] (clr-angular.js:12106) at clr-angular.js:12531
 at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
 at QueryList.push../node_modules/@angular/core/fesm5/core.js.QueryList.forEach (core.js:17092)
 at clr-angular.js:12530
 at SafeSubscriber.schedulerFn [as _next] (core.js:12621)
 at SafeSubscriber.push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/Subscriber.js.SafeSubs
```

Comment: You can [edit] your question, please don't post stacktraces in comments

Comment: Can you provide a demo? Without a sample we can't really debug what is happening. We have a lot of starters at https://stackblitz.com/@clr-team